# EditText setText not working in ActionBar CustomView

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-edittext

I have a custom `ActionBar` with search field using `EditText` following [this tutorial](http://blog.rhesoft.com/2015/03/30/tutorial-android-actionbar-with-material-design-and-search-field/). I am trying to `setText` the `EditText` using string. I have tried this, but it not working:

```
    ActionBar action = getSupportActionBar();
    action.setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);
    action.setCustomView(R.layout.search_bar);    
    edtSeach = (EditText) action.getCustomView().findViewById(R.id.edtSearch);
                edtSeach.setText(tv1);
```

I tried to experiment using normal `EditText`, it works:

```
input = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.input);
input.setText(tv1);
```

Why `setText` is not working when I put it under `ActionBar` `CustomView`? How to get it to work?

Comment: what happens when you call it does it crash?

Comment: It does not crash. `setText` simply not working. The `EditText` remains empty.

Comment: your actionbar is a toolbar right?

Comment: Yes, it is a toolbar.

Comment: okay your solution is `Toolbar tool = getSupportActionBar();` you might need casting i guess, now call findviewbyid on your toolbar and see

Comment: I do have this in my Activity, but I am using ActionBar with CustomView
`mToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);`

Comment: yes your your Toolbar is acting as your ActionBar as toolbar is like actionbar if you do setSupportActionbar and put toolbar in it, it is the toolbar serving as the customview, just try it and let me know sir

Comment: Sorry, do you mind to write me an answer? I am a self learner in Android and I don't get your meaning.

Comment: hmm yes i am writing to you a solution  `edtSeach = (EditText) toolbar.findViewById(R.id.edtSearch);
                edtSeach.setText(tv1);`

Comment: Following the answer by Robert Gil, I get incompatible type error.

Comment: and following my last comment prior to this you get?

Comment: @user2872856  look at the answer.

Comment: http://javatechig.com/android/actionbar-with-custom-view-example-in-android

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I try the tutorial code and it's work if you want to set edittext to some By default value then put like this.

Define variable :

```
private String tv1 = "Google";
```

And then Use this code.

```
 action.setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true); //enable it to display a
            // custom view in the action bar.
            action.setCustomView(R.layout.search_bar);//add the custom view
            action.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false); //hide the title

            edtSeach = (EditText)action.getCustomView().findViewById(R.id.edtSearch);

             edtSeach.setText(tv1);
```

It will set the Google in your edittext.

Comment: @user2872856 glad to help you.

Answer (score 0):

Use this code one instead:

```
Toolbar action = getSupportActionBar();
action.setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);
action.setCustomView(R.layout.search_bar);    
edtSeach = (EditText)action.getCustomView().findViewById(R.id.edtSearch);
              edtSeach.setText(tv1);
```